# Regex for every group of spaces at the beginning of a line

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I am trying to fix the regex for a [highlight indentation](https://github.com/antonj/Highlight-Indentation-for-Emacs/) module for emacs. The way it works currently is by highlighting once every %s spaces:

```
"\\( \\) \\{%s\\}"
```

And here's a sample result of the behavior for some Verilog code:

[image]

The current regex works well for the indentations in the beginning of each line. However, there is an undesirable artifact that sequences of spaces that are not at the beginning of the line are also matched by the regex. **I would like to modify the regex to match the above behavior, but only at the beginning of the line. Here's what I want** (I had to manually draw it):

[image]

Here's what I've tried. You can see from the result that the behavior isn't right.

```
"^\\(\\( \\) \\{%s\\}\\) \\{1,\\}"
```

Result:

[image]

Also tried

```
"^\\(\\( \\) \\{%s\\}\\)\\{1,\\}"
```

Result:

[image]

Here is the relevant code, but I apologize It is not a working example. Please use the above link for a working example.

```
(set (make-local-variable 'highlight-indentation-current-regex)
     (format "\\( \\) \\{%s\\}" (- highlight-indentation-offset 1)))
(font-lock-add-keywords nil `((,highlight-indentation-current-regex
                               (1 'highlight-indentation-face))))
```

Comment: I'm well acquainted with regexps, but I'm not familiar with how font-locking is done. If you're willing to explain it I might be able to help. Is it just a matter of writing a regexp that matches and then specifying which group inside it should be highlighted?

Comment: If that's the case then your second regexp seems to have one too many spaces. Could `"^\(\( \) \{%s\}\)\{1,}"` work?

Comment: You may want to try [indent-guide](https://github.com/zk-phi/indent-guide) instead.  It's an alternative implementation of this feature, which may work better.

Comment: @BruceConnor, I'm afraid I don't have much knowledge or understanding of font-locking either. This is someone else's module and I am a beginner in elisp and regexps. I tried your suggestion but it did not match anything.

Comment: @lunaryorn, Its a useful suggestion, but I really like highlight-indent except for this one problem.

Comment: Won't something like this do: `"^\\(\\(\\ \\)\\{%s\\}\\ \\{%s\\}\\)+"`? Sorry, I don't have this mode installed, just trying to guess. There would be a problem with `%s` probably, because you'd need to specify it twice. But you could also (maybe) move it outside the outermost group, depending on what exactly the function which uses it does.

Comment: @wvxvw, I am getting "File mode specification error: (error: "Not enough arguments for format string.")" I tried a few variations of it, but I couldn't figure out what doesn't have enough arguments.

Comment: `%s` must be the specification it complains about. The original has only one, but I didn't know if multiple instances are allowed. So if that didn't work you could try it like so: `"^\\(\\(\\(\\ \\)\\ \\)\\{%s\\}\\)+"`, but what Stefan suggests is better because instead of complex regex it would be testing for something Emacs already has a predicate for.

Comment: @wvxvw, The result of that regexp is similar to the second result I posted. I am trying to use Stefan's answer but I can't get it to work right either.

Comment: I'm looking for the regexp for "\\( \\) \\{%s\\}" AND "\\(^ +\\)". That is, a group of spaces AND line-leading spaces. Anyone know how to do a logical and within a regexp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your current font-lock rule looks like:

```
(,highlight-indentation-current-regex (1 'highlight-indentation-face))
```

you could use

```
(,highlight-indentation-current-regex (1 (if (save-excursion (skip-chars-backward " \t") (bolp)) 'highlight-indentation-face)))
```

Comment: I added the font-lock rule to the question. Its not the same as your post, but I am trying to understand how to take what you made and apply it to what I have.

Comment: I adjusted my code to fit the rule you use.  It's guaranteed 100% untested, so it might require minor tweaks to get it to work, of course.